# How can I convert Bootstrap 3 input group addons to Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert some code from bootstrap 3 to 4.

These inputs work fine in bootstrap 3, unfortunately it doesn't work in boostrap4 is there any way to accomplish this?

Bootstrap 3:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">1</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);"><span class="input-group-addon">text1<br><br>text2<br><br>text3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">2</i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);"><span class="input-group-addon">text1<br><br>text2<br><br>text3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">1</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);"><span class="input-group-addon">text1<br><br>text2<br><br>text3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">2</i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);"><span class="input-group-addon">text1<br><br>text2<br><br>text3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: [check this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/)  Basically you have to wrap `span` with another `div` with class `input-group-prepend` and on `span` add `class="input-group-text" `

Comment: thanks, I applied various arrangements and margin and voila!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                   <span class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">1</span>
                   </span>
                   <div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="input-group-append d-flex flex-column">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="border-top-right-radius: .25rem;">text1 </span>
                    <span class="input-group-text">text2 </span>
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="border-top-right-radius: 0;">text3 </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                   <span class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">2</span>
                   </span>
                   <div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" readonly style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="input-group-append d-flex flex-column">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="border-top-right-radius: .25rem;">text1 </span>
                    <span class="input-group-text">text2 </span>
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="border-top-right-radius: 0;">text3 </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

You can read about the differences between Bootsrap v3 and v4 in here:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#input-groups

Comment: Hey thanks, very nice approach, I tried something different but both can help to anybody

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution approach.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text mr-2">1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 ml-n2 mr-n2">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text ml-n2">
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none;padding: 0;margin:0;">
                                <li class="mb-2">
                                    1
                                </li>
                                <li class="mb-2">
                                    2
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    3
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```